# What is the difference between inBuy[1] and inBuy in the end of these two sentence?

Tags: pine-script-v5

```
inBuy := not inBuy[1] and close < l1Long[1] ? true : inBuy[1]

inBuy := inBuy[1] and close > stopPrice ? false : inBuy
```

I know that the `inBuy[1]` statement is in the state of calling the value of `inBuy` in previous the bar，but what does `inBuy` mean without `[]`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what value "inBuy" represents but I can tell you the difference between the two.

```
ibuy alone refers to the value of the current bar. (right most on chart)
inBuy[0] is identical to inBuy alone, without sequence reference (as above)
inBuy[1] refers to 1 bar ago from the current bar. 
inBuy[2] refers to 2 bars ago from the current bar.
```

Etc, etc.